# ActionBar text's background color not changing

Tags: java, android, xml

I put an ActionBar into my app and changed the background color, as I'll show below. Oddly enough, the color behind the text on the ActionBar won't change. ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OJyy.jpg))

I looked around and found this: 
`<item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@null</item>`

But I would prefer not to use it because then my minSdk has to be set to 14, whereas I have it at 11 now. I did try boosting it up to 14 to see if this tag would work, but I again couldn't get the color to change.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Many thanks in advance for your help.

**Styles.xml:**

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/myWhite</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/myWhite</item>
    <!--Support Library compatibility-->
    <item name="background">@color/myBlack</item>
</style>
```

**drawable/actionbar_background**:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid android:color="@color/myBlack" />
</shape>
```

**menu/login.xml**:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

      <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/settings_label"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

And finally, inside the LoginActivity class, the **onCreateOptionsMenu method**:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: I had a similar problem, just that mine was that I had set the style in the theme tag and when trying to change the background programmatically I got always the same issue as yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out I was using the wrong attribute -- instead of using android:background in the styles.xml file, you need to use android:windowBackground. android:background changes all sorts of other things, too.